# Where to find vshard replicaset object for performing remote call on it

Tags: tarantool

I use tarantool-vshard module. Documentation says I can perform a remote call on a replicaset using the following syntax:

```lua
replicaset.call(replicaset_uuid, function_name, {args}, {options})
-- or callrw or callro
```

Where can I get this replicaset object?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform call for specific bucket you can use

```lua
local replicaset = vshard.router.route(1)
replicaset:call(...)
```

Or you can iterate over all replicasets:

```lua
for uuid, replicaset in vshard.router.routeall() do
    replicaset:call(...)
end
```

Note that you don't have to pass uuid explicitly, you can use colon notation `:call()` instead.